# Call to a member function build() on null - when non-null data given

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

Using CakePHP 4.x to try and generate a URL as per the [documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/url.html).

According to the docs you should be able to do this:

```
echo $this->Url->build([
    'controller' => 'Posts',
    'action' => 'view',
    'bar',
]);

// Output
/posts/view/bar
```

This doesn't work.

If I execute that in a controller method it gives

> Error: Call to a member function build() on null

This makes no sense because `build()` is being passed an array, not a `null` value.

My controller contains

```
use Cake\View\Helper\UrlHelper;
```

Simple question: how do you get this to work?

Comment: `$this->Url` is null, not the data being passed into it.

Comment: Helpers are for views only, not for controllers! In a controller you use `\Cake\Routing\Router::url()`.

Comment: @ndm  In this case it's an API and the controller has to return a URL to the "view" in a scenario where it saves a new record. It would be preferable if there was a consistent way to generate URLs since the output would be exactly the same - it's either the correct URL, or it isn't.

Comment: The view in CakePHP's "MVC" is on the server side, it's the class that is actually called `View`, and everything that revolves around it, eg templates, elements, cells, etc... The view helper pretty much only exists so that URLs generated in the view are being HTML entity encoded by default, which is something that most people likely do not want when returning URLs on an API endpoint.